# How to add tabular lines, matrix lines to arrays in LyX?

Tags: lyx, matrices, wysiwyg

[image]

The buttons such as `Set all lines`, `Set right line`, `Set left line` and `Set bottom line` are not activated with arrays as the example on the left while they are activated on the example on the right with tabular environment.

My goal is to learn to create upper triangularizations like on the right below. For that one needs to turn the array into tabular environment somehow or find a way to get the line options in matrices/arrays/tabulars activated.

**How can I add the tabular lines or matrix lines in LyX?**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Method:** Add modifications directly to the option `Horizontal:` like in tabular environment in LaTeX.

[image]

**2. Method:** Click the right mouse button and choose one of the `Add line` options.

[image]

for example `Add Line Above` and `^M W A`, `^M W Z` in the dropdown.

**3. Method:** use the panel pictures a bit like in Word (feature that works every-now-and-then, perhaps a bug in LyX 2.1.4?)

[image]

Comment: I don't see the option to add a vertical line. Do you know the reason?

Comment: In my environment, the vertical line is not rendered in the interface, but appears correctly in the pdf output.

Comment: Method 3 using table toolbar doesn't work for array, buttons are not enabled. Can you explain how you display the panel for method 1 with array? or is that valid only for matrix?